# Maven test assembled jar

Tags: java, maven, integration-testing

Unit tests are great, but the final step in testing is running and verifying the assembled jar on the test environment:

```
java -Dcom.foo.Environment=TEST -jar Foo-App-jar-with-depdendencies.jar
```

So far what I've discovered in the Surefire and Maven plugins assume you are using separate test resources, not the production product and verifying the finished project itself.  What is an on-the-rails way to accomplish this in Maven?

Comment: Quality assurance and regression testing is normally done using a whole different set of tools. You *could* always create a separate deployable JAR containing your test classes, but I'm not sure what that would buy you (much) over running the tests on your build machine?

Comment: @Perception so you're saying I'm asking for a future that is usually left up to a continuous deploy/integration component?

Answer (score 1):

That what you are describing are integration tests and are supported by maven using the [maven-failsafe-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/) which is after the [package lifecycle phase](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference) which means the packaging of the jar-with-dependencies is already done.

This can be accomplished by using a separate module where you can use maven-execute-plugin to execute your jar-with-dependencies.